# The displayed data depends on another data, downloaded from the database asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, devexpress

**Description of the problem:**

I'm downloading column "Login" from the database to my selectbox.

I have two more fields: 2x textbox
I try to make a selection in selectbox, after selection,

they were downloading to textboxes from the same row in the database, but from the Name and Surname columns

**Model code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using AppEcp.Models;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;


namespace App.Models
{
    public partial class Members_Model
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Login { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
    }


    public partial class MembersDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public MembersDbContext() { }

        public virtual DbSet<Members_Model> Members { get; set; }

        public MembersDbContext(DbContextOptions<MembersDbContext> options) : base(options) { }



        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)  { }

    }
}
```

**Controler code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using App.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using DevExtreme.AspNet.Data;
using DevExtreme.AspNet.Mvc;

namespace App.Controllers
{
    public class MembersController : Controller
    {


        private readonly MembersDbContext _membersContext;

        public MembersController(MembersDbContext membersContext)
        {
            _membersContext = membersContext;
        }


        public IActionResult GetItems(DataSourceLoadOptions loadOptions)
        {
            var GetMethod = _membersContext.Members.Select(i => new
            {
                i.Id,
                i.Login, 
                i.Name,
                i.Surname


            });

            return Json(DataSourceLoader.Load(GetMethod, loadOptions));
        }

        public ActionResult GetNameAndSurname() 
        {

            return;
        }

    }
}
```

**I tried:**
 to use jquery in this ajax, .OnValueChanged in selectbox to run funtion in controler

**View**

```
    @(Html
       .DevExtreme()
       .SelectBox()
       .ID("id_login")
       .DataSource(d => d
           .Mvc()
           .Controller("Members")
           .Key("Id")
           .LoadAction("GetItems")
       )
       .DisplayExpr("Login")
       .ValueExpr("Id")
       .SearchEnabled(true)
       .OnValueChanged("getMyFuntion")
    )
     @(Html.DevExtreme().TextBox()
       .ID("tx01")
       .ReadOnly(true)
    )
     @(Html.DevExtreme().TextBox()
       .ID("tx02")
       .ReadOnly(true)
    )


<script>
    function getMyFuntion() {

        var Vtx01= "?";
        var Vtx02 = "?";

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "@Url.Action("GetNameAndSurname")",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: "?",
            success: function (res) {
                document.getElementById("tx01").value = "?";
                document.getElementById("tx02").value = "?";
            },
            failure: function (response, error) {
                alert(error);

            },
            error: function (req, status, error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });

    }
</script>
```

I don't know how to approach this, I can't write the code to load values ​​from the database into textboxes (depending on the selected item on the selectbox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give parameter to Controller function GetNameAndSurname(string login)
and then something like:
Controller

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetNameAndSurname/{login}")]
public ActionResult GetNameAndSurname(string login){
   urDB.Where(x=>x.login == login).Select(s=> new Members_Model {
      Name = s.Name,
      Surname = s.Surname
   });
.. and some stuff u want too... than return...
}
```

then ajax will be look like:

```
$.ajax({    
type: "GET",
url: "@Url.Action("GetNameAndSurname")",
data: {"Login" : valueOfLoginFromUrWebPage}
......
});
```